# UNIX regex -find between date range

Tags: regex, unix, find

Can you help i need to find directories within a specified date range.

The date format is - 20160501

Say i wanted to find the Bolded dates only, see below.

20160101 **20160201 20160301 20160401** 20160501

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking?

```
find . -name "20160[234]01" -type d
```

Leading to

```
$      mkdir 20160101 20160201 20160301 20160401 20160501

$     find . -name "20160[234]01" -type d
./20160201
./20160301
./20160401
```

**Edit**

> This uses global pattern, not regex

Comment: You sir are a legend :)

Comment: Can i ask you to help on an expanded version then please.

i need to select the directories with dates between

20140729

20140921



20140916  20140917  20140921  20140924
20140810  20140815  20140829 20140921

How can this been done please :)

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean. How can something be "between" 8 different dates?

Comment: You don't need the pipe inside brackets. `[234]` is more correct. Your pattern will match `20160|01`

Comment: Note also that the argument to -name is a glob pattern not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of dates to browse with your `find`:

```
find 20160401 20160301 20160201 -type d
```

And to look for a specific file `file_name` in the directories

```
find 20160401 20160301 20160201 -name "*file_name*"
```

Same with `grep` on `find` result:

```
find 20160401 20160301 20160201 |grep file_name
```

or for the expanded version in comment,

```
find 20140729 20140921 \
     20140916 20140917 \
     20140921 20140924 \
     20140810 20140815 \
     20140829 20140921 -name "*file_name*"
```

(note: `\` are only to format the command on several lines)